# Use ansible _facts or _info module

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I wish to create an Ansible module that will read and return the version of my software installed on a system.  Reading the ansible [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html) it's not clear if the result should become part of the facts dictionary, or info (so create a mysw_facts or mysw_info module).  But I suspect an _info module is more appropriate based on the docs statement to use _info for

> information on individual files or programs.

As well, since the version will change as my (next) module can upgrade my software, will the ansible facts be redetected/updated?

Comment: For something as basic, have you considered deploying a simple executable file in the local facts on each concerned target? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#adding-custom-facts

Comment: Since I already have a json formatted file with version info in my program directory, I thought it would make sense to just read that.  (Also, this is a learning exercise for me)

Comment: My point is that it will be much easier (and still something to learn...) to drop a one liner in an executable local facts file to read that version in the yaml file on those nodes rather than creating a full blown module. If you still decide to walk that path, your case is a bit on the edge IMO. It's both information about installed software and about individual software. I'd try both info and facts approach and keep the most convenient for my specific use. In any case, if you're not going to distribute this publicly, this should not have any impact anyway.